# Unexpected syntax error in IDL when redefining using if, then and endif

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, idl

Getting an unexpected syntax error message when trying to redefine constants using if, then and endif

```
if(ipeak eq A3(n3-1)) then begin
;if wave packets too close then need to redefine halfl and half: 
        if(A3(ipeak)-A3(ipeak-1) lt 2*half) then 
        halfl=(A3(ipeak)-A3(ipeak-1))/2.
        if (half gt nn-A3(n3-1) )then halfr=nn-A3(n3-1)
endif
```

With the syntax error occurring on the second if statement at the end over the then statement. Am I being stupid or have been staring at this too long because I cannot see the issue properly

Answer (score 0):

You either need a `$` after the hanging `THEN` or remove the carriage return.  It is also advisable to use []'s instead of ()'s when indexing to avoid `undefined function errors`.

```
IF (ipeak EQ A3[n3-1]) THEN BEGIN
  ;; if wave packets too close then need to redefine halfl and half: 
  IF (A3[ipeak]-A3[ipeak-1] LT 2*half) THEN halfl = (A3[ipeak] - A3[ipeak-1])/2.
  IF (half GT nn - A3[n3-1]) THEN halfr = nn - A3[n3-1]
ENDIF
```